# How to add function or method in jquery FormValidation Engine?

Tags: jquery-plugins

How can I validate the value of time using form validation engine? I'm using a timepicker (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) plugins to insert date and time in same field that gave a value of "**2011-05-25 00:00:00**" 00:00:00 is a default value if the user not tick on the slider.

time must not be in "00". Do i need to trim the value to validate it? I'm stuck with this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('time', function(value, element) {

    return this.value.search(/00:00:00$/) != -1;

}, 'Please enter a valid time.');
```

Comment: Your awesome sir! I got the logic and try to convert it to jquery formValidation Engine [link](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) and got it!!! thank you very much sir!